# Am I understanding dependency graphs correctly?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

$\textbf{Definition}:$ For a collection of random variables $(X_i)_{i \in V}$,indexed by the vertices $V$ of a graph $G = (V, E)$, $G$ is called a $\textit{dependency graph}$ if for any disjoint subsets $S, T \subset V$, $(X_i)_{i \in S}$ and $(X_i)_{i \in T}$ are independent.

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Let $F$ be some measurable function, and consider the sum
$$ S_N = F(X_1, X_2) + F(X_2, X_4) + F(X_3, X_6) + F(X_4, X_8) + F(X_5, X_{10}).$$

If we consider each summand as a random variable, would this be the correct dependency graph?

[image]

Comment: How does the definition actually interact with $G$? I think you need to add some requirement about the edges between $S$ and $T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a slight problem with your definition: $G$ is a dependency graph if for any disjoint $S, T \subseteq V(G)$ with no edges between them, we have $(X_i)_{i\in S}$ and $(X_i)_{i \in T}$ are independent.

I also want to highlight that there can be multiple dependency graphs for the same set of random variables. The graph you drew is *a* dependency graph for these five random variables. The third and the fifth terms in the sum don't share any random variables (which are independent) with the other terms, so they can be isolated vertices in the dependency graph. Taking the remaining three terms to be a triangle in the dependency graph means that there is nothing left to check.

There is a slightly better dependency graph in this case, however. We don't need the edge between the first and fourth terms. Of course, depending on $F$, the dependency graph could be even smaller.